# add_post_meta Adds post meta but the value is blank

Tags: metabox

My plugin uses a metabox to save post meta. I have three option in the metabox. Everything is saving/updating/deleting correctly except for this:

```
add_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key_duration, $new_meta_value_duration, true );
```

If I echo out the values right before this call:

```
echo $post_id.' '.$meta_key_duration.' '.$new_meta_value_duration;
```

I get:

```
52 expDuration 10
```

this is correct since I chose "10" as the value to be saved. The database is showing the post_id and meta_id correctly but the value isn't being saved.

Comment: `add_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key_duration, "4", true );` isn't saving "4" into the DB either

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating a value, you want to use [`update_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta). When you set `$unique` to `true` in `add_post_meta`, nothing will happen if the meta key already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `update_post_meta()` which will make sure that `$meta_key` already exists. If it does not, `add_post_meta` is called instead and its result is returned.